# Remove prefix from value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of similar values inside a select:

```
<select id="selectbairro" name="selectbairro">
<option value="AC_Itapetininga_Text1"></option>
<option value="AC_Itapetininga_Text2"></option>
<option value="AC_Itapetininga_Text3"></option>
</select>
```

I want to create a var that gets the current selected value WITHOUT the prefix (Text1, Text2, Text3) and insert it inside that:

```
$("#selectbairro").change(function() {
var id = $(this).val();
// here //
});
```

Like I showed below `var id = $(this).val();`, I have a var that gets the current selected option value WITH THE PREFIX, so I need something starting from this.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just use replace?  as in $this.val().replace("AC_Itapetinaga_","")

Comment: All values before suffixes have same length? If the are, can you just use `.length` or not?

Comment: @user2744722 no :( I will different values, like AM_Blabla_Blabla

Comment: @CommercialSuicide no. Always different

Comment: is always the text after the last underscore?

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).val().split("_").pop()
```

this splits your string into an array by underscore and then pops off the last one as someone just mentioned add join to turn the array (with the last thing popped off) into a string

```
var id = $(this).val().split("_").pop().join("_");
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU. Works perfectly.

Comment: Need to add `.join("_")` to turn it back to a string.

Comment: I was confused. That's not exactly what I want. I want everything EXCEPT what your result gets, in other words, I want everything EXCEPT the suffix. Your code gets the suffix.

Comment: I updated the answer to use join as Barmar mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Thanks.

```
var id = $(this).val().split('_',2).join('_');
```